# Async DB save throwing DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have an application that saves to DB Asynchronously , Now the issue is If there are Duplicates in the payload (same Id), or the Application receives multiple (Id same) payload to multiple instances, Hibernate creates insert for both of them and the one which was received later throws DataIntegrityViolationException as the Id is already present. There is `@retryable` which retries the 2nd time, Hibernate creates update statement and the 2nd payload updates the existing record.
How to avoid the Exception.

I tried `@Transactional` and `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` as well. but it didn't work. I am using Spring JPA and `@Async`

`[{"id":1, "name":"abc"}, {"id":1, "name":"efg"}]`